# Setting a limit on number of checkboxes that can be chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, limit

I have searched other similar questions on here and tried to replicate them, but I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

I am only wanting one checkbox to be able to be checked. I set the limit with `limitCal` and am checking the siblings.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function (bool) {
        return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
    }    
    function packageSelect() {
      var limitCal = 1;
        $('.calendar-check').on('change', function () {
            $(this).parents('.product-wrap:first').find('.checkmark-img').fadeBoolToggle(this.checked);
            if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limitCal) {
                this.checked = false;
            }
            $('#next1').fadeBoolToggle($('.product-check:checked').length > 0);
            var prods = [];
            $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function () { prods.push($(this).val()) });
        });
    };
    packageSelect();
```

```css
.calendar-check {
  display: none;
}
.product-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.checkmark-img {
    display: none;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.package-check-toggle {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.package-setup {
    display: none;
    margin: 40px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#calendar-box-wrap {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.calendar-box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 4%;
    position: relative;
}
.calendar-selection-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar-box">
                            <div class="product-wrap">
                                <label for="cal-2year" class="package-check-toggle">
                                    <img src="images/calendar-package.png" alt="2-year Photo Gift" class="calendar-selection-img">
                                    <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
                                </label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-2year" value="2-year Calendar">
                            </div>
                        </div><div class="calendar-box">
                            <div class="product-wrap">
                                <label for="cal-whiteboard" class="package-check-toggle">
                                    <img src="images/calendar-package.png" alt="Whiteboard Photo Gift" class="calendar-selection-img">
                                    <img src="images/checkmark-circle.png" class="checkmark-img total-center">
                                </label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="calendar-check" id="cal-whiteboard" value="Whiteboard Calendar">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: The simplest thing to do when you only want one option checked is to use a radio button not a checkbox

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I will need to use the checkbox logic for another section that would have a limit greater than 1, so I need to understand this for that as well.

Comment: You haven't really mentioned what's wrong with the code you have. When I run your snippet, I see two (broken) images, so I have no idea what you're trying to do. How about trimming down your code to only be just enough to show the issue (see [mcve] for hints on how to do that).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The code is trimmed down as much as I can. My question is 100% complete. When you click on the broken image it shows another image....this is how you can you can click on more than one thing.

Comment: It's really not as trimmed down as much as you can. The same problem could be demonstrated using the following HTML: `<input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox">`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I included it the way I did because that is how it is structured. I would rather post it this way to show people how it is, rather than doing some very basic way of showing it when it could be something in my existing code that is throwing it of. Thanks for your input, but I know how to ask a question on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of what you're trying to do. Basically, intercepting the click event of the checkbox allows you to prevent the default action (checking the checkbox). The value of `checked` for `this` is going to be the value it would be if the click is successful. So, if the checkbox would be unchecked, let the click happen. Also let the click happen if the number of checked checkboxes is less than or equal to the limit. Otherwise, stop the checkbox from getting checked. I've set the limit for this example to 2 just for demonstration.

```js
var limit = 2;
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function (e) {
  if (!this.checked || $('input:checkbox:checked').length <= limit) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this. I added it to my code, but for some reason whenever I uncheck a box it won't let me re-check it. https://jsfiddle.net/vm8563dy/

Comment: Nevermind it works now. Weird. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is there anyway to do this: If they would click another option (with one already selected) that is unchecked the previous option and then selected the one they just clicked on?

Comment: Yeah, but that's a different question :).

Comment: Great. I will ask one soon or Monday and include  the link in here. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to work on this, but I'm getting stuck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819900/adding-removing-checkmark-to-different-inputs-with-a-limit/42820007?noredirect=1#comment72778463_42820007

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allCheckBoxs = document.querySelectorAll("input")
let limit = 2
allCheckBoxs.forEach( el => {
  
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if(el.checked){
      limit--
      
      if(limit < 0){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Sorry, you are over the limit")
      }
      
    }else{
      limit++
      console.log(limit)
    }
    
  })
  
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Be careful with this because this is assuming ES6 is an option for the OP.

Comment: Just an example, Babel can take care of this

Comment: Any idea how I can make this work with my existing function?